# Why am I seeing this bizarre behaviour?

Tags: arrays, c, dynamic, knapsack-problem

The code is recursive dynamic programming for the 0/1 Knapsack problem.
So let me start by saying that the code seems correct because when I run it, It shows results but only if I uncomment the `printf` line (please see the highlighted part) and it has nothing to do with the solution (I used it only for testing purpose) which I find totally weird. Can somebody please tell me why is this happening.

```c
int main() {    

    int DP_Recursive(int W, static int wt[], static int val[], int n, static int dp[][]);

    static int wt[5] = { 5, 10, 20, 30 };
    static int val[5] = { 50, 60, 100, 120 };

    static int dp[5][60]; //marker 2-D array

    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
        for (int w = 0; w <= 50; w++) {
            dp[i][w] = -1;
        }
    }

    printf("The total loot is %d$.", DP_Recursive(50, wt, val, 2, dp));
}

//Recursive D.P. solution 
    
int DP_Recursive(int W, static int wt[], static int val[], int n, static int dp[5][60]) {
    //-------**HIGHLIGHTED PART**-----------
    printf("%d", dp[2][30]);
     //--------------------------
    //Base case
    if (n == 0 || W == 0)
        return 0;

    if (dp[n][W] != -1)
        return dp[n][W];

    if (wt[n-1] > W) {
        dp[n][W] = DP_Recursive(W, wt, val, n - 1, dp);
        return dp[n][W];
    } else {
        dp[n][W] = max(val[n-1] + DP_Recursive(W - wt[n-1], wt, val, n-1, dp),
                       DP_Recursive(W, wt, val, n-1, dp));
    }
    return dp[n][W];
}
```

Comment: Your iniitalization loop for `dp` goes out of bounds, leading to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: A simple rule of thumb: whenever you see `<=` in a C for-loop terminating condition, pay extra attention to make sure your bounds are larger by 1.

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  Amongst several other problems, the needed header file: `stdio.h` is not included.  2)  the modifier `static` is seriously misused.  Perhaps you meant `const`

Comment: this prototype, in the body of function: `main()`  1) should be before the function: `main()` 2) should NOT contain the `static` modifier

Comment: OT: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers, like: 5, 30, 50, 60  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  'magic'' numbers are numbers with no basis.  Suggest using a `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: OT: regarding; `static int wt[5] = { 5, 10, 20, 30 };` and similar statements:  Much better to let the compiler calculate the amount of room needed rather than hardcoding a sizing value

Comment: @RavikantSharma: you can accept the answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 5):

There are multiple issues int the code:

- **[Major]** The prototype for `DP_recursive` is incorrect: use `int DP_Recursive(int W, int wt[], int val[], int n, static int dp[5][60])` in both the function declaration **before** the `main()` function (outside the body of `main`) and for the function definition itself.
- **[Minor]** the arrays in `main()` do not need to be declared `static`.
- **[Major]** the initialization loops run one step too far: `for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)` iterates 6 times with `i` ranging from `0` to `5` inclusive. You should use `<` instead of `<=` in both loops. As a rule of thumb, always check twice before using `<=`, and always prefer excluded upper bounds.
- **[Major]** the inner initialization loop uses `50` instead of `60` as the upper bound, causing the array to be partially initialized and result incorrect (undefined behavior) instead of `110`. It is better to use a `countof` macro to get the number of elements in an array.
- **[Minor]** you should end the output with a newline (`\n`)
- **[Minor]** `main()` should return `0` upon successful termination.
- you did not post the definition of `max`, it is advisable to define it as a function.
- the include file `<stdio.h>` is missing too.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int DP_Recursive(int W, int wt[], int val[], int n, int dp[5][60]);

int max(int a, int b) {
    return a < b ? b : a;
}

#define countof(a)  (sizeof(a) / sizeof((a)[0]))  // number of elements in an array

int main() {    
    int wt[5] = { 5, 10, 20, 30 };
    int val[5] = { 50, 60, 100, 120 };
    int dp[5][60]; //marker 2-D array

    for (size_t i = 0; i < countof(dp); i++) {
        for (size_t w = 0; w < countof(dp[i]); w++) {
            dp[i][w] = -1;
        }
    }
    printf("The total loot is %d$.\n", DP_Recursive(50, wt, val, 2, dp));
    return 0;
}

//Recursive D.P. solution 
    
int DP_Recursive(int W, int wt[], int val[], int n, int dp[5][60]) {
    //-------**HIGHLIGHTED PART**-----------
    printf("%d ", dp[2][30]);
    //--------------------------

    //Base case
    if (n == 0 || W == 0)
        return 0;

    if (dp[n][W] != -1)
        return dp[n][W];

    if (wt[n-1] > W) {
        dp[n][W] = DP_Recursive(W, wt, val, n - 1, dp);
        return dp[n][W];
    } else {
        dp[n][W] = max(val[n-1] + DP_Recursive(W - wt[n-1], wt, val, n-1, dp),
                       DP_Recursive(W, wt, val, n-1, dp));
    }
    return dp[n][W];
}
```